# What's the phrase/expression for practising martial arts?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Recently, I took up Taekwondo and ended up with a question: How can I say I practise a martial art in English? Is it just practise or is there another verb for it?
In my mother tongue I say (roughly translated) "I fight Taekwondo" or "I train Taekwondo", but it sounds kind of weird in English.

Comment: "I'm learning Taekwondo."  or, if you're trying to imply that you already know the art: "I do Taekwondo." "I know Taekwondo."  ("[I know karate!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowKarate?from=Main.IKnowKungFu)")

Comment: Personally, I always say, "I _study_ taekwondo." (Third dan and progressing...) Or, "I practice taekwondo three or four times a week."

Answer (score 2):

You've answered the question yourself and I believe there's no other verb for it. The meaning of the word 'practise' implies engaging oneself in a rehearsal.

The word 'training' at the end of the day, implies repetitiveness (with the aim of getting better and better).

Answer (score 2):

I would venture that you 'study' taekwondo.

As @choster indicates these oriental martial arts are not simply about fighting. They work within philosophical systems that involve to some degree 'mind over matter'.

So I think you are a 'student of taekwondo', and that even the higher 'dans' still regard themselves as 'students'.

Answer (score 1):

You could *do* taekwondo, as pointed out in Doc's comment, but more formally we would say

> I practice taekwondo. (American English)
>
> I practise taekwondo. (British English)

While you could say you *fight* taekwondo and be understood, as it is indeed a *martial* art, a practitioner would point out that it is not just fighting, but also practice patterns and forms, all within the framework of a larger philosophical system— a trait it shares with many other East Asian martial arts and their derivatives. To say *he fights* as a competitive sport suggests boxing, though I have heard people say things like *he fights MMA*.

Comment: As I said, to say 'fight' is a rough translation for me seeing the art goes beyond fighting, so I'm thankful for the explanations; now I can speak about my new activity without being worried about misunderstandings.